# Apache POI Evaluate Formula in SXSSF workbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In my project I use the `SXSSFWorkbook` (Apache-POI 3.9) class to manage a large spreadsheet.
Now I need to evaluate formulas for some cells, so I tried with a FormulaEvaluator like this

```
...
SXSSFWorkbook streamingWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
...
FormulaEvaluator fe = streamingWorkbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
...
fe.evaluateInCell(cell);
```

but doing so, an exception is thrown

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFCell cannot be cast to org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell
at     org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:177)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:44)
```

...

The direct cause of this error is clear: the method `.evaluateInCell` takes a `Cell` object, but internally casts the `Cell` into a `XSSFCell`. Since I'm passing instead an `SXSSFCell` the exception is thrown.

So the question is: Is there a way to implement formula evaluation in streaming workbooks (SXSSF)?

Comment: Evaluating formula cells needs the whole workbook to be in memory to resolve references, which SXSSF explicitly avoids, so I think you're probably out of luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR - The support you need isn't in the older 3.9 version that you're using, so you'll need to upgrade to 3.13 beta 2 or later.

Your problem is that you're using too old a version of Apache POI. That's why you're getting exceptions when you try to evaluate SXSSF cells. As [detailed towards the end of the Formula Evaluation documentation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#sxssf), for SXSSF formula evaluation, you need to be using 3.13 beta 2 or later.

One thing to be aware of though - Formula Evaluation needs not only the cell with the formula in to be in memory, but also any other cells it refers to, and any they refer to. As such, a call to `FormulaEvaluator.evaluateAll()` is unlikely to work; you'll normally need to evaluate cells one-by-one just after writing. You'll also struggle with formulas which refer all over the place, as they'll only work if the cells they refer to are in the current window, and haven't been flushed to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to add the below dependency looks like you are missing other jars for XSSF

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>????</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I think the problem is not caused by dependencies, but is related to the inner implementation of POI.
The method `.evaluateInCell` takes a `Cell` object, but internally casts the `Cell` into a `XSSFCell`. Since I'm passing instead an `SXSSFCell` the problem occurs.

Comment: by the way, thanks for pointing me to maven-driven dependencies :)

Answer (score 0):

the bellow image showing the problem(in SXSSF you can't evaluate the formula)
[image]

Comment: SXSSF can evaluate formulas! You just need to be using a new enough version, and have the cells in memory, see the [POI formula docs for details](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#sxssf)

Comment: SXSSF can evaluate formulas only when stream is not flushed.